# How to name figure in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to name figures like this:

```
import matplotlib as plt
for i in range(0,3): 
    plt.figure('Method%s',%i)
```

But seems it is not possible this way.

another way I found is using super title but still it does not work:

```
    from pylab import *
    for i in range(0,3):
       fig = gcf()
       fig.suptitle('Method%s',%i)
```

do you know any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to **use** the figures you are going to create, it may be a good move to store them in some kind of data structure. In my example I will use a list and I will give also an example of using later one of the figures that have been instantiated.

Re naming your figures according to a sequence number, you are correct with the general idea but not with the details, as it happend that in `plt.figure()` to have a user defined name you have to use a keyword argument that is not named `name` as one could expect, but … `num` …

```
figures = [plt.figure(num="Figure n.%d"%(i+1)) for i in range(3)]
#                     ^^^
...
figures[1].add_axes(...)
...
```